# Issue in saving chart in Android Studio

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to call the save function of the MPAndroidChart library in order to save a chart I have created.  I can create the chart fine but when I try to save the chart the following occurs:

```
07-21 14:52:42.879 5818-5818/com.example.a1003137m.profitcalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.a1003137m.profitcalculator, PID: 5818
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a1003137m.profitcalculator/com.example.a1003137m.profitcalculator.ChartActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:855)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:834)
       at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:801)
       at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.Chart.getChartBitmap(Chart.java:1492)
       at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.Chart.saveToGallery(Chart.java:1597)
       at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.Chart.saveToGallery(Chart.java:1636)
       at com.example.a1003137m.profitcalculator.ChartActivity.onCreate(ChartActivity.java:55)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

I can see that the problem is the illegal argument exception, but would anyone happen to know why this is being thrown?

I have the permissions in my manifest and I request them upon running as well.

Here is the line in question where the above stacktrace occurs:

`mChart.saveToGallery("chart",50);`

Activity code:

```
package com.example.a1003137m.profitcalculator;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.ValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.XAxisValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IBarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    protected BarChart mChart;
    private String choice;
    // Storage Permissions
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        choice = intent.getStringExtra("choice");
        Bundle data_bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
        verifyStoragePermissions(this);
        boolean check = setChart(data_bundle);
        if (check){
            mChart.saveToGallery("chart",50);
        }
    }



    private boolean setChart(Bundle data_bundle) {

        mChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        mChart.setDescription("Test");
        ArrayList<String> year = (ArrayList<String>) data_bundle.getSerializable("year");
        ArrayList<Double> depreciation = (ArrayList<Double>) data_bundle.getSerializable("dep");
        ArrayList<Integer> population = (ArrayList<Integer>) data_bundle.getSerializable("pop");


        ArrayList<BarEntry> dep_entries = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<BarEntry> pop_entries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i< depreciation.size(); i++){
            BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(depreciation.get(i).floatValue(),i);
            dep_entries.add(entry);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i< population.size(); i++){
            BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(population.get(i).floatValue(), i);
            pop_entries.add(entry);
        }

        BarDataSet barDep = new BarDataSet(pop_entries,"Population");
        barDep.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        BarDataSet barPop = new BarDataSet(dep_entries, "Depreciation");
        barDep.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);

        List<IBarDataSet> sets = new ArrayList<>();
        sets.add(barDep);
        sets.add(barPop);

        mChart.setDescription("Bar Chart of data for "+choice);
        BarData bar_data = new BarData(year, sets);
        mChart.setData(bar_data);
        boolean success =true;
        return success;


    }

    /**
     * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
     *
     * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
     *
     * @param activity
     */
    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: You need to provide a code sample otherwise it's hard to tell from just one line. The only thing I can say is to make sure the chart is rendered before trying to save the error your getting is because a bitmap has a height or width of zero.

Comment: I suspected this is the problem, do you have any recommendations on how to wait until chart is rendered until saving?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your workflow. Maybe disable a save button until it's rendered. You could try calling invalidate() before saving.

Comment: I'm waiting on Android Studio reloading, so I shall put the activity code in the main post in a second.

Comment: Code is there @Ben

Comment: Have you tried calling mChart.invalidate() after you call mChart.setData()? Also I would advise against doing the save in onCreate() What you have now will save every time the activity is recreated, which could be often if the user rotates the device.

Comment: @Ben I have put it in my current version of the code but it is still giving me the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding a button to my layout which saves the graph when clicked.  This makes sure that the graph is fully rendered and attached before attempting to save it to your device.

Full code:

```
package com.example.a1003137m.profitcalculator;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.ValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.XAxisValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IBarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ChartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    protected BarChart mChart;
    private String choice;
    // Storage Permissions
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chart);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        choice = intent.getStringExtra("choice");
        Bundle data_bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
        verifyStoragePermissions(this);
        mChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        setChart(data_bundle);
    }




    private void setChart(Bundle data_bundle) {


        ArrayList<String> year = (ArrayList<String>) data_bundle.getSerializable("year");
        ArrayList<Double> depreciation = (ArrayList<Double>) data_bundle.getSerializable("dep");
        ArrayList<Integer> population = (ArrayList<Integer>) data_bundle.getSerializable("pop");


        ArrayList<BarEntry> dep_entries = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<BarEntry> pop_entries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i< depreciation.size(); i++){
            BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(depreciation.get(i).floatValue(),i);
            dep_entries.add(entry);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i< population.size(); i++){
            BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(population.get(i).floatValue(), i);
            pop_entries.add(entry);
        }

        BarDataSet barDep = new BarDataSet(pop_entries,"Population");
        barDep.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
        BarDataSet barPop = new BarDataSet(dep_entries, "Depreciation");
        barDep.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);

        List<IBarDataSet> sets = new ArrayList<>();
        sets.add(barDep);
        sets.add(barPop);

        mChart.setDescription("Bar Chart of data for "+choice);
        BarData bar_data = new BarData(year, sets);
        mChart.setData(bar_data);



    }

    /**
     * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
     *
     * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
     *
     * @param activity
     */
    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        // Check if we have write permission
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }


    public void saveChart(View view) {

        BarChart saveChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
        saveChart.saveToGallery("chart",50);

    }
}
```